# WinForms designer strips away event handler assignments when upgrading forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing brownfield development, and have to deal with lots of old forms with code that looks like this.

```
// 
// Button1
// 
Button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(556, 447);
Button1.Name = "Button1";
Button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 23);
Button1.TabIndex = 112;
Button1.Text = "Restart kontor";
Button1.Click += Button1_Click;
```

If I try to edit one of these forms, the form is upgraded. All the identifiers will then have the "this" qualifier prepended. Unfortunately Visual Studio 2015 will also simply strip away all event handler assignments in the file. That means the last line in the above example snippet will simply vanish.

Why does this happen? Is there a very simple way to prevent it?

I have found a workaround that is reasonably quick to work through for each form. The workaround is posted as an answer. It will cut my work upgrading these forms from days to hours.

If anybody knows of a quicker way, a proper fix perhaps, I'd like to know.

Comment: How are you trying to edit the forms - in the designer, or by manually editing the designer-generated code? What added that event handler in the first place? (I thought the designer usually used delegate-creation-expressions, although I could be wrong.) Never manually edit designer-generated code, unless you intend to never, ever use the designer again - the designer "owns" that code, and *will* undo changes you make to it.

Comment: The forms have not been edited manually. This is a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: So what generated the `Button1.Click += Button1_Click;` code? I don't think I've seen any versions of VS that generate that code. If you're saying that was generated by VS, do you know which precise version?

Comment: This is really old source. I don't know how old, but many of the forms don't have the designer source file. Instead it's all in one file. Don't know if that gives a clue as to how old the oldest parts are.

Comment: Right, so that suggests VS2002/VS2003 - and that also suggests it's entirely feasible that the code *was* added manually. Can you not look at the source history?

Comment: There is no history that far back. Nothing in that source suggests anything but the designer was used 99% of the time. The handlers are always in the exact same positions, for the components and for the form itself. Very precise and tidy, unlike the source that was authored.

Comment: Base on my understanding, `private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` and 
`Button1.Click += Button1_Click;` get created at the same time you double-click a button on [Design]. Since event handler gets stripped when you edit a form, have you tried doing a double-click if it solves the issue?

Comment: Yes, have tried double click on components and events in Properties pane, and it always generates new handlers. It can also cause a rearrange of components in the form's source, so then I have no good way to compare old and new. Even if something like that worked, it would be too time consuming.

Comment: Good point. I also encounter this problem occasionally when editing winforms where old event gets overlapped by new event on double-click or like your issue, gets stripped.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround**

Editing an entire form to fix broken event handler assignments can be very time consuming. This workaround speeds up the process significantly, by fixing the source before the designer tries to upgrade it. (I do not know if "upgrade" is the proper term, but who cares...)

Before allowing the designer to upgrade the form, edit the form source manually in this way.

Edit all lines with event handlers so that they explicitly do a new System.EventHandler. All you have to do to find the relevant lines is to search for "+=". This is what the line in the snippet from the question will look like then.

```
Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

When this is done, you must somehow trigger the designer to upgrade the form. This can be done e.g. by changing the title of the form via the designer, and then change it back. The designer will now hopefully correctly upgrade all lines. The entire snippet in the question will then look like this after upgrade.

```
    // 
    // Button1
    // 
    this.Button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(556, 447);
    this.Button1.Name = "Button1";
    this.Button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 23);
    this.Button1.TabIndex = 112;
    this.Button1.Text = "Restart kontor";
    this.Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
```

So far this way to handle the problem leaves me with upgraded forms that are easy to compare with the original forms, which is important when verifying the upgrades.